# Axios POST to Heroku is blocked by CORS - Network Error: 503

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios, cors

I'm using **MERN** Stack and everything was working fine until I made some changes to the UI (Moving code to different components, changing styles,...).

- I didn't change any code in the **Axios** request and only this **POST** request doesn't work, the other requests work normally.
- I have already setup **CORS** in my backend
- I can access `my-project.herokuapp.com/insert` link and there's no error in the Heroku logs. No error thrown in the client or server terminal.
- When I click on the **Add To List** button in the form, the `addToList` function which contains the **Axios POST** request doesn't send the data to the database like it used to.
- After 30 seconds - this error appears:

[image: Network Error 503]

Please help me understand what is going on and how to fix this. I have looked for other solutions but I don't know how to apply to my case.
Thank you! :)

---

**Here's my code:**

**addToList function on the client-side:**

```
const [foodName, setFoodName] = useState('')
const [isVegetarian, setIsVegetarian] = useState('')
const [priceRange, setPriceRange] = useState('$')
const [foodUrl, setFoodUrl] = useState('')
const [foodList, setFoodList] = useState([])

const addToList = async (event) => {
      event.preventDefault()
      try {
        await Axios.post(
        "https://my-project.herokuapp.com/insert", 
        {
          foodName: foodName,
          isVegetarian: isVegetarian,
          priceRange: priceRange,
          foodUrl: foodUrl,
        }
        )
        .then(() => {
          setFoodName('')
          setIsVegetarian('')
          setPriceRange('$')
          setFoodUrl('')
        })
      } catch(err) {
        console.error(`The error is ${err}`)
      }
    }
```

**Dinner.js - Mongoose Schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const DinnerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    foodName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    isVegetarian: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    priceRange: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    foodUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
})

const Dinner = mongoose.model("dinners", DinnerSchema)
module.exports = Dinner
```

**Server's index.js and the endpoint that doesn't work:**

```
const express = require("express")
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
require("dotenv").config()

const DinnerModel = require('./models/Dinner')

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(
    'mongodb+srv://linktoDB', 
    {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
    }
)

// Create:
app.post("/insert", async (req, res) => {
    const foodName = req.body.foodName
    const isVegetarian = req.body.isVegetarian
    const priceRange = req.body.priceRange
    const foodUrl = req.body.foodUrl

    const dinner = new DinnerModel(
        { 
            foodName: foodName, 
            isVegetarian: isVegetarian,
            priceRange: priceRange,
            foodUrl: foodUrl
        }
    )

    try {
        await dinner.save()
        res.send("Inserted successfully")
        
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
})

// Creating a port:
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001, () => {
    console.log("Server is connected.")
})
```

**My backend's package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.20.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "devStart": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "validator": "^13.7.0"
  }
}
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

I added this code and it still doesn't work:

```
const corsOptions = {
 "origin": "*",
 "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
 "preflightContinue": false,
 "optionsSuccessStatus": 204,
}

 app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

**Here's the preflight request and response when I try to add the document. One with status 204 and one with status 503:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1IcS.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzH8d.png

### UPDATE 2

I found out what the problem is when I check the payload. Please check my answer below.
Thanks everyone for helping me with this!

Comment: It may sound silly. Did you save your backend file and restart the server??

Comment: Do you see any error being thrown at the backend?

Comment: @ikhvjs Yes, I did. I even committed the client and server folder again just to make sure. But the error is still there :/

Comment: @TheWhiteFang Just the error in the console which I caught in the `addToList` function. The backend's terminal doesn't say anything.

Comment: You will get this error when you are running your app locally (localhost). To run your app locally without this error, use a proxy which adds `CORS` headers to the proxied request such as [CORS Anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what caused the 503 Error when checking for the **Payload** of the POST request in the Network tab.

- It was receiving an empty string for my `isVegetarian` value.
- That empty string happened because I changed the `isVegetarian` **schema** type from Boolean to String but forgot to change the initial state to a specific value:
  `const [isVegetarian, setIsVegetarian] = useState('')`
- In the **Schema**, I set **isVegetarian** to **required: true** so it won't accept empty strings.

-> So if you have the CORS config right and still have the same 503 error. Maybe check for the **Network** tab for preflight requests, response & payload to see if there's any leftover code you need to review.

Comment: How come your backend doesn't pop up this `isVegetarian` error ?

Comment: @ikhvjs I'm not sure, that's why it took me days to debug this. The backend terminal didn't crash or throw any error.

Comment: I think I know why. you should place your `new DinnerModel()` inside the `try block`. Also, you should send an error like `res.send(err);` in your `catch block`

Comment: @ikhvjs I tried moving the `const dinner = new DinnerModel({object: object,..})` into the `try block` and sent an error in `catch block` then tried to reproduce the error again. The backend node terminal still doesn't say anything, only the frontend console with the 503 Error like before.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. what if you console.log(err) in the `catch block` before `res.send` ? I think it should track the error when you try to initialize your modal.

Comment: @ikhvjs  Here's the screenshot of my code, is it normal that it's still the same result as above? https://paste.pics/FMVJS